# Getting the right 'topic' per record

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

My problem is that I wont get the right records. As you can see each topic has a board_id and it needs to show the right board but now it only shows the `stel jezelf voor` and the last record needs to be `nieuws & events`

[image: How it looks like now]

Klanten db
[image]

Database with the boards
[image]

Database with the topics
[image]

The code to show the the records:

```
<?php
   $toppic = $app->get_topics();
   foreach($toppic as $topic){
    echo '<div id="topic">';
    echo '<div id="topicimg">';
      if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'])) { 
   echo '<img class="img-circle" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'].'/'.$topic['foto'].'" />';
      } else {
         echo '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-user img-circle"></i>';
      }
      echo '</div><div id="topictekst">';
      echo '<b><a href="https://tom.lbmedia.nl/reactie"> '.$topic['topicnaam'].'</b></a>'; 
      echo '<a> - ' . $topic['voornaam'] . " " . $topic['achternaam'] . '</a>' ;
      echo '<a style="float:right; margin-top:15px;"> reacties</a> <span style="float:right; color:grey; margin-top:15px"class="fa fa-comment"></span>';
      echo '<hr><a><span class="badge bg-red">' . $board['topic'] . '</span></a>';
      echo '</div></div>';
     }
  ?>
```

The functions for this code are:

```
public function get_boards(){
    $getBoards = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM boards ORDER BY id DESC");
    $boards = $this->database->resultset();

    return $boards;

}

public function get_topics(){
    $getTopic = $this->database->query("
    SELECT topics.*, klanten.foto, klanten.voornaam, klanten.achternaam FROM topics 
    LEFT JOIN klanten ON topics.klant_id=klanten.id
    ORDER BY id ASC");
    $topics = $this->database->resultset();

    return $topics;

}
```

Summary, What I want:

I want it to show the right board with the right topic. As you can see the salespage has a `board_id 2` so it needs to show ' Nieuws & events ' and not ' stel jezelf voor '

**EXTRA**

Also if possible I want it to make the whole record/div to be clickable. any tips/tricks for that?

Comment: are You sure klanten table has this records?

Comment: yes? @Whencesoever it has nothing to do with that + as you can see it shows the foto = photo so it has nothing to do with that, I need to get a way to show the right board_id

Comment: Need to see `klanten` table. i think you are trying to join `topics` & `boards` table

Comment: @Sinto I need to do that yeah! but I am getting confused how to do it you got an answer? + added klanten table

Comment: What is this `klanten` table ???

Comment: I added the `klanten ` db

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do some think like below `JOIN`, can you check

```
SELECT boards.topic, topics.topicnaam 
FROM topics 
LEFT JOIN boards ON boards.id = topics.boards_id 
ORDER BY topics.id ASC
```

If there is a table called `klanten` as you said, the query would be like:

```
SELECT boards.topic, topics.topicnaam, klanten.foto 
FROM topics 
LEFT JOIN boards ON boards.id = topics.boards_id 
LEFT JOIN klanten ON topics.ledenpagina_id = klanten.ledenpagina_id 
GROUP BY topics.id 
ORDER BY topics.id ASC
```

Comment: There is! look at the question I added a pic of the `klanten db`

Comment: You want to get record as `salespage` + `Nieuws & events` + `tom.jpg` & other two `topics` with `stel jezelf voor` + `tom.jpg`... ???

Comment: What I want it that it shows the things it does right now but now it doesnt get the right `boards_id` by the records, so as you can see the last record has a `boards_id` 2 so I doesnt need to show `stel jezelf voor` but it needs to show `Nieuws & events`

Comment: What are you saying.. I do not get it. Was there any error. What is you expecting result & what are you getting now? I have written query for you function `get_topics()`. Please add necessary fields in query with respective table names. OR please run the query directly in DB & see the result.

Comment: And please change `$board['topic']` to `$topic['topic']` in the HTML section in your code.

Comment: `$topic['topic']`is not what I want `$board['topic'] ` is what I want and it works perfect

Comment: Only after updating your query. Do you have run the query directly in DB

Comment: I edited your question with the results + edited the query because you made a little mistake

Comment: I do not asked you any question. I was trying to know your requirement. If you have got answer its fine

Comment: I showed you what what it returned so you know that? you asked me to run it in the DB so I did? whats next?

Comment: I think the issue is with `LEFT JOIN klanten ON topics.ledenpagina_id = klanten.ledenpagina_id` that should be `LEFT JOIN klanten ON topics.klant_id = klanten.id` - I also not sure what  `ledenpagina_id` field is but perhaps adding `WHERE ledenpagina_id = 1` will do the trick and without the `GROUP BY`s (You need to explain the DB structure for better answer that will not be based on assumptions)